# How to save Image in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to save an image to core data .
I get an image from camera or photo library an store it to global UIImage variable .
How can I insert this image to newPerson.image

```
let newPerson = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Person", into: manageObjectContext) as! Person
newPerson.age = age
newPerson.city = cityInput.text
newPerson.image = ????
```

I am using swift 4.

Comment: Did you try to save it as Data (NSData) ???  You can use the function `UIImagePNGRepresentation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `UIImage` to `NSData` and save.

To save: let `data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`

To load: `let image = UIImage(data: data)`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image into Data form. Then save it as Binary data.

Comment: Im new to core data. Can you share some sample code on how that is done and why?